# Yii2 multiple instances of the same model with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, model, yii2

I am trying to use multiple instances of the same model using javascript append. However, I do not know how to do that. Therefore, I create the following code.

**javascript**

```
var div_input = $('#input');
div_input.append('<input type="hidden" name="'+c+'_round" value="'+c+'" />');
```

variable "c" is a increasing running number. for example, first time i append the name will be "1_round". and second time will be "2_round" and so on.

**Controller**

```
 $loop = true;
    $i = 0;
    do{
        $i++;
        if (!empty($_POST[$i . "_round"]))
        {
            $round = $_POST[$i . "_round"];
            $model->model_round= $round;
            $model->save();
        }else{
            $loop = false;
        }
    }while($loop);
```

The problem here is it will always only save the last loop of data and not every loop of data. Please help me with this. New to Yii2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize new instance of `$model` each time in loop

i.e

```
    $saved_array = [];
    $loop = true;
    $i = 0;
    do{
        $i++;
        if (!empty($_POST[$i . "_round"]))
        {
            $model = new model();
            $round = $_POST[$i . "_round"];
            $model->model_round= $round;
            if($model->save()) {
                $saved_array[$model->id] = True;
            } else {
                $saved_array[$model->id] = $model->getErrors();
            }
            unset ($model);
        }else{
            $loop = false;
        }
    }while($loop);
```

You can finally analyize if model is saved or not if not saved what are the errors with the `$saved_array`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use input name as array

```
<input name="round[]">
```

Then loop it

```
$round = $_POST['round'];
foreach( $round as $key => $n ) {
// code here
}
```